# How to connect Child Row in Expandable List View to a specific row in an SQL Database Table

Tags: java, android, sqlite, expandablelistview, assets

I am trying to make some kind of a catalog type android application. The catalog is about some materials. My idea is using an Expandable List View which consists Child Rows. The Child Rows are filled with clickable texts, which are material names, and will show the material's data in an Alert Dialog (Marking, Quantity, Profile, Length, Weight, Total Weight). The material's database was made in DB Browser and kept in the assets folder in Android Studio.

Here is the database table (sample):

[image: Database Table Sample]

Here is the Expandable List View activity:

[image: Expandable List View Activity]

Here is the code:

DatabaseHelper.java

```java
package com.example.sutetpedia;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    String DB_PATH = null;
    private static String DB_NAME = "marking";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "MARKING_DATA";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 10);
        this.myContext = context;
        this.DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";
        Log.e("Path 1", DB_PATH);
    }




    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }



    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public Cursor getRow(String key){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME + "where marking = "+key,null);

        return res;
    }




}
```

MyExpandableListAdapter.java

```java
package com.example.sutetpedia;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.sutetpedia.DatabaseHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.sutetpedia.ChildRow;
import com.example.sutetpedia.ParentRow;
import com.example.sutetpedia.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {



    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    String key;

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ParentRow> parentRowList;

    private ArrayList<ParentRow> originalList;

    public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context context
            , ArrayList<ParentRow> originalList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.parentRowList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.parentRowList.addAll(originalList);

        this.originalList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.originalList.addAll(originalList);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return parentRowList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return parentRowList.get(groupPosition).getChildList().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return parentRowList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return parentRowList.get(groupPosition).getChildList().get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ParentRow parentRow = (ParentRow) getGroup(groupPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_row, null);

        }


        TextView heading = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parent_text);

        heading.setText(parentRow.getName().trim());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ChildRow childRow = (ChildRow) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
        }



        final TextView childText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_text);
        childText.setText(childRow.getText().trim());
        final View finalConvertView = convertView;
        childText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor res = myDb.getRow(key);
                if(res.getCount() == 0) {
                    // show message
                    showMessage("Error","Nothing found");
                    return;
                }
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while (res.moveToNext()) {
                    buffer.append("Marking :"+ res.getString(0)+"\n");
                    buffer.append("Quantity :"+ res.getString(1)+"\n");
                    buffer.append("Profile :"+ res.getString(2)+"\n");
                    buffer.append("Length :"+ res.getString(3)+"\n\n");
                    buffer.append("Weight :"+ res.getString(4)+"\n\n");
                    buffer.append("Total Weight :"+ res.getString(5)+"\n\n");
                }

                // Show all data
                showMessage("Data",buffer.toString());


            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }

    public void showMessage(String title,String Message){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(Message);
        builder.show();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public void filterData(String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();
        parentRowList.clear();

        if (query.isEmpty()) {
            parentRowList.addAll(originalList);
        }
        else {
            for (ParentRow parentRow : originalList) {
                ArrayList<ChildRow> childList = parentRow.getChildList();
                ArrayList<ChildRow> newList = new ArrayList<ChildRow>();

                for (ChildRow childRow: childList) {
                    if (childRow.getText().toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                        newList.add(childRow);
                    }
                } // end for (com.example.user.searchviewexpandablelistview.ChildRow childRow: childList)
                if (newList.size() > 0) {
                    ParentRow nParentRow = new ParentRow(parentRow.getName(), newList);
                    parentRowList.add(nParentRow);
                }
            } // end or (com.example.user.searchviewexpandablelistview.ParentRow parentRow : originalList)
        } // end else

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I run the code into my device and it successfully compiled. But when I clicked one of the Child Rows, the application stops after a few seconds.

Please tell me if there is anything I should change in my code. Thanks before!